# Looping through *args elements without a loop

Tags: python

I am trying to print out a succession of coefficients of a simple polynomial using `*args`

I roughly understand how `*args` works and I know how to use a simple loop to print out each coefficient, but in a `__repr__` function that is supposed to return only one thing as the return value of function, I am confused how to do this...

```
class Polynomial:

    def __init__(self, *coefficients):
        self.coeffs = coefficients

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Polynomial( {} )".format(self.coeffs)    

p1 = Polynomial(1, 2, 3)
p2 = Polynomial(3, 4, 3)

print(p1)                               # Polynomial( (1, 2, 3) )
print(p2)                               # Polynomial( (3, 4, 3) )
```

The outcome of `print` is what comes after the comments obviously, though what I am after is this format:

```
1x^2 + 2x + 3
3x^2 + 4x + 3
```

I have tried the following, but I cannot seem to get it right.

```
    def __repr__(self):
        # return "Polynomial( {}x^2 + {}x + {} )".format(self.coeffs)
        # return "Polynomial( {0}x^2 + {1}x + {2} )".format(self.coeffs)
        # return "Polynomial( {0}x^2 + {1}x + {2} )".format( enumerate(self.coeffs) )
```

Is there a neat way of doing this without having to loop through the `args` elements and all in one go within the `return` statement?

Comment: `__repr__` isn't different from any other callable in that it returns a single value. It doesn't mean loops cannot be used within functions and methods.

Comment: To your specific question: is the degree of the polynomial known to be exactly 2? From your attempts it looks like it is, but then you wouldn't need *args so much.

Comment: @Lev Levitsky Not necessarily, but I would like to get my head around `*args`, so I am starting off easy to see if I can access every coefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `*` syntax in `__repr__` as well:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "Polynomial( {}x^2 + {}x + {} )".format(*self.coeffs)
```

However, if you want to have `__repr__` adjust to the degree of the polynomial, you probably need a loop of some sort:

```
def __repr__(self):
    degree = len(self.coeffs) - 1
    polystr = ' + '.join('{}x^{}'.format(term, degree-i)
         for i, term in enumerate(self.coeffs))

    return "Polynomial( {} )".format(polystr)
```

Comment: Bless you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I never thought of trying to use the same format with `*` inside `return`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I'm taking the coefficients as a `list`):

```
exp = len(self.coeffs)
i = 0
s = ""
while exp > -1:
    s += str(coeffs[i]) + "x^" + str(exp) + " "
    exp -= -1
    i += 1
return s
```

Or, if you'll always have 2 as the highest exponent, you could use `*` to select all of the `coeffs`, as in `.format(*self.coeffs)`.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful. But I would like to find out how I can access the elements of `*args` and use them in one statement within `return` rather than writing a complete method for it. For example: something like `"{0}x^2 + {1}x + {2}".format(*args[0], *args[1], *args[2])`